# Forward slash in Bash on Mac

Tags: php, regex, bash, phpunit

I have this bash(version 3.2 on MacOS) function

```
rtf(){
    local filter=${1//\*/\(\.\)\*};
    local bin="vendor/bin/phpunit --filter="
    local command=$bin"'/"$filter"/i'";

    echo $command;
    $command;
}
```

What it's suppose to do is run phpunit with proper regex, here i am converting `*` to `(.)*` and wrapping filter to be case insensitive.

**Now**

```
$ rtf test*fail
// results in 
vendor/bin/phpunit --filter='/test(.)*fail/i'
```

The problem is that parsed command works perfectly fine(matched test cases run), when i run directly at terminal. But it does not when function `rtf` tries to call it in last line. Somehow phpunit can not find matchings for this.

I can believe that the issue is with forward slash in the `$command` variable. Can any suggest a fix?

Comment: Store the command in an array instead of a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `eval "$command"` rather than `$command`. See following example:

```
[STEP 101] $ cmd="echo 'foo'"
[STEP 102] $ $cmd
'foo'
[STEP 103] $ eval "$cmd"
foo
[STEP 104] $
```

And it's not safe to write `rtf test*fail`, instead it should be `rtf "test*fail"` otherwise `test*fail` will be expanded to filenames if the pattern matches some files.

Comment: works fine for me, i don't know why someone down voted it.

Comment: there are other solutions (it's true!) which they think are better. :)

Comment: its probably because `eval` is not a very safe solution, but because they are the sort to downvote without comment we will never know

Comment: `eval` is almost always the wrong solution for things like this; it blurs the line between data and executable code (even more than usual in shell scripts), so things you thought were just data can wind up getting parsed as shell syntax and commands. Using `eval` safely requires a detailed understanding of the shell parsing process, but in practice it's almost always used as a *substitute* for understanding shell parsing (as is the case here), which is a really really bad idea.

Comment: Although I'll give you credit for at least putting `"$cmd"` in double-quotes. I usually see just `eval $cmd` recommended, which has even more opportunities for misparsing and chaos.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, nothing is perfect, even the world itself. you cannot explain all about shell programming in one post. do you also need to mention that `echo` is not portable and recommend `printf` be used? then you also need to explain why `printf "$str"` is almost wrong and should use `printf %s "$str"`? then you also need to explain what the magic `%s` is and then also list other formatting like `%d`, `%#x`, `%-5s`, ...

Comment: ... also you can mention that `function name()` is more safe then just `name()` since `name` can be an existing alias but you also need to mention that `function name()` is not portable and in ksh, `function name()` and `name()` has totally different behavior.

Comment: i forgot to mention that the `;` char in the end of the line is not necessary in the question.

Comment: i forgot to mention that in ERE, `(.)*` can be simplified as `.*`. and since i'm talking about ERE i have to explain what BRE is too.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: see [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Long answer: Putting commands (or parts of commands) into variables and then getting them back out intact is complicated. When the shell expands a variable on the command line, if the variable was in double-quotes it's not parsed; if it was not in quotes, spaces in it are parsed as argument breaks, but quotes and escapes are not parsed. In either case, putting quotes in the variable's value does nothing useful -- they're treated as data, not as shell syntax. To see this, consider a simple example:

```
$ echo expr '5 * 3'
expr 5 * 3
$ command="expr '5 * 3'"
$ echo $command
expr '5 Desktop Documents Downloads Library Movies Music Pictures Public 3'
```

Note the difference in output between the two `echo` commands. In the first one, the single-quotes were parsed by the shell and removed before the string was passed to `echo`, so they didn't get printed. In the second one, the single-quotes were treated as data, passed to `echo`, which printed them; also, since the `*` wasn't in quotes (as far as the shell was concerned), it *was* expanded to a list of files in the current directory. Any guess what running `$command` will do? Let's try:

```
$ expr '5 * 3'
5 * 3
$ $command
expr: syntax error
```

... it works fine when I enter the command directly, but executing it from a variable fails because the expression `'5 Desktop Documents Downloads Library Movies Music Pictures Public 3'` is invalid.

So, what should you do about it? One possibility is to use `eval`, as @pynexj suggested, but `eval` has a well-deserved reputation as a bug magnet. Scripts that use `eval` typically work great in testing, but then sometime later a shell metacharacter shows up in some data, `eval` recognizes it and includes it in the parsing process, and mayhem ensues. So don't do this, it's a bad idea.

What should you do instead? Well, generally the best and simplest option is to skip storing the command at all, and just execute it directly. If you want to print an equivalent command, do that separately:

```
rtf(){
    local filter=${1//\*/\(\.\)\*}
    echo vendor/bin/phpunit --filter="'/$filter/i'"
    vendor/bin/phpunit --filter="/$filter/i"
}
```

Note that in the `echo` command, I added single-quotes around the string -- these aren't really part of the command, but they'll be printed, making an *equivalent* command to what's about to be executed.

There are other options, including putting the command in an array, but that seems like overkill here. If you're interested, see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for more info.